# PHP variable declaration shorthand (similar to JavaScript)

Tags: php, variables

In JavaScript, I can do this:

```
var somevar = {
    propertyTwo : false,
    propertyThree : "hello!"
}

var test = somevar.propertyOne || somevar.propertyTwo || somevar.propertyThree

alert(test); //displays "hello!"
```

Is there a similar functionality in PHP for this?
Haven't been able to find anything online.

I tried this, but PHP just treats it like a comparison and echo's `1` (`true`)

```
$somevar = array(
    'propertyTwo' => false,
    'propertyThree' => "hello!"
);

$test = $somevar['propertyOne'] || $somevar['propertyTwo'] || $somevar['propertyThree'];

echo $test; //displays '1'
```

Not really a big deal if there isn't, but I figured that with all of the bells and whistles provided in php 5.x, there would be some kind of shorthand for assigning the first true value in a list of values to a single variable like that.

I suppose I could write a function.

EDIT :

As I suspected, PHP doesn't have the same quirk.

Quick function I wrote

```
function assign_list($list){
foreach($list as $v)
    if(isset($v) && $v) return $v;
return false;
}
```

Just pass it an array of stuff

Comment: no. you can't do this in PHP. It's a handy trick in JS, but it's due to quirks in the JS syntax. Those quirks don't translate into PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work in `PHP >= 5.3`, but you will still receive a `Notice Error` because `propertyOne` is not defined.

```
<?php
$somevar = array(
    'propertyTwo' => false,
    'propertyThree' => "hello!"
);

$test = $somevar['propertyOne'] ?: $somevar['propertyTwo'] ?: $somevar['propertyThree'];

echo $test; //displays 'hello!'
```

You could however work around this by supressing the variables, but it is **highly unrecommended**:

```
$test = @$somevar['propertyOne'] ?: @$somevar['propertyTwo'] ?: @$somevar['propertyThree'];
```

Comment: Cool I like this answer. I can see why that wouldn't be recommended to suppress the variables like that, but for my production scenario that might be exactly what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work in PHP, and here's why:

```
$somevar['propertyOne'] = false;
$somevar['propertyTwo'] = true;

$test = $somevar['propertyOne'] || $somevar['propertyTwo'];
```

Imagine typing that query into an if statement:

```
if( $somevar['propertyOne'] || $somevar['propertyTwo'] ){ ... }
```

This will return true (evaluates to 1) if either variable is true.

Now, if we make all of the variables = `false`:

```
$somevar['propertyOne'] = false;
$somevar['propertyTwo'] = false;

$test = $somevar['propertyOne'] || $somevar['propertyTwo'];
```

The variable returns false (evaluates to 0).

Another thing we can do is:

```
$somevar['propertyOne'] = true;
$somevar['propertyTwo'] = true;

$test = $somevar['propertyOne'] && $somevar['propertyTwo'];
```

This will return true (evaluates to 1) as both variables meet the criteria.

This means that we can do things like this in PHP though:

```
$test = $somevar['propertyOne'] || $somevar['propertyTwo'];
if($test){ ... }
```

**TL,DR:** In PHP you are storing the result of the expression into a variable, not doing any validation on anything.